# using "\" character in python strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print 'This\' in **Python IDLE** output. I try with the below strings but I couldn't do it :

1:

```
>>> "This\"
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

2:

```
>>> "This\ "
'This\\ '
```

**Q1: Why?!**

**Q2: How I can print 'This\' in output?**

---

I put different letters right after `\` in the string and the out put make me more confused :

For letters such as **r**,**t** and **n** :

3:

```
>>> "This\n"
'This\n'
>>> "This\r"
'This\r'
>>> "This\t"
'This\t'
```

But for letters such as **w**,**q** and **y** :

4:

```
>>> "ali\w"
'ali\\w'
>>> "ali\q"
'ali\\q'
>>> "ali\y"
'ali\\y'
```

As you see above, we have two `\` in the output for second group, while it is one `\` character for first group!

**Q3: What is the difference between these letters?**

Comment: What do you think ``\`` in a string **means**? A big hint is given in the output of `print "This\ "`; see that the backslash was doubled?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't know! What it means?!

Comment: If you took a quick look at the [reference documentation for string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), or the [tutorial on strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) perhaps the difference became easier to see?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can I have 'This\' in output or not?

Comment: OK, Thanks. So I'll delete the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [Python tutorial on strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

> Besides numbers, Python can also manipulate strings, which can be expressed in several ways. They can be enclosed in single quotes (`'...'`) or double quotes (`"..."`) with the same result. **`\` can be used to escape quotes.**

Emphasis mine.

The backslash, in regular string literals, is the *escape symbol*, it signals a special character sequence. See the [String literal reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for a full overview, but sequences like `\n` and `\t` are used to specify special characters that would otherwise be hard to include in a string value, such as the [newline character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) or tabs. As such, the backslash before a quote (`\"`) *escapes the quote*, making it possible to include it in a string literal.

You'll need to double the backslash to make it a regular backslash:

```
>>> print "This\\"
This\
```

Comment: Using `print "This\\"` solved my problem, Thanks. But I can't have `This\\` in the output using `"This\\"` yet! (without `print` command)!

Comment: Oops! I can't make comment it also! :D please try to comment `This\\`

Comment: @TheGoodUser: the string *representation* (echoed in the interactive shell or when part of a list or other container or when you explicitly use the `repr()` function) will try to give you a value you can paste right back into Python code. As such, backslashes in the original string are doubled to make them valid in a string literal again.